# Gtk3 python combobox with CellRendererToggle

Tags: python, checkbox, combobox, gtk, cellrenderer

I'm trying to make a Gtk with Combobox with checkboxes in it. But "my" checkboxes are inactive, though I tried in many ways - I just cannot click them. Here is a fragment from my program

```
self.listst= Gtk.ListStore(str)
combost= Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model(self.listst)
self.rend = Gtk.CellRendererToggle()
self.rend.connect("toggled", self.cell_toggled)        
combost.pack_start(self.rend, False)
for stac in ["first option","second option"]:
    self.listst.append([stac])
cellrendst = Gtk.CellRendererText()
combost.pack_start(cellrendst, True)
combost.add_attribute(cellrendst, "text", 0)
self.buttbox.pack_start(combost,True, True,0)


def cell_toggled(rend, path):
    self.rend[path][1] = not self.rend[path][1]
```

I presume I must pack this CellRendererToggle() in something and set active state of cellrenderertoggle but I don't know how to join it to combobox then.

Comment: Your model will need a column of boolean type to store the active state for each item. This sounds like an awkward UI choice, though; what are you trying to do?

Comment: It's a part of the interface to a database, giving user a possibility to select  one or more parameters in condition

Comment: It sounds like a list of checkboxes would be better for that UI, instead of a combobox (which implies single selection). What does your UI look like?

Comment: Its a window with panel for choosing values of parameters (4-6) on the top. Some of parameters I must use for filtering have about 20 possible states, and must give possibility to choose two or three of them at once, So if I placed list of checkboxes I would have main window full of checkboxes

Comment: Ok, I dont like the answer but I see, that's the right one - thank you

Comment: I told you how you can use your design the first time: add a boolean column to your GtkListStore and bind that column tot he GtkCellRendererToggle's `active` property. Did that not work?

Comment: Also if it wasn't clear, do not take my lack of response in a certain amount of time as meaning you don't have an option; I was just trying to understand your problem and seeing if there was a better solution to that. The way you want to do it is completely doable; in fact, it should just work...